# Referencing a japanese/chinese string in gradle.properties from strings.xml results in an unknown behaviour

Tags: android, string, gradle, localization

I'm referencing a gradle variable from a string.xml the following way:

gradle.properties

```
APP_NAME_JAPANESE="日本語"
```

build.gradle

```
resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME_JAPANESE', APP_NAME_JAPANESE
```

strings.xml

`<string name="app_name">@string/APP_NAME_JAPANESE</string>`

The generated file generated.xml have the following string

`<string name="APP_NAME_JA" translatable="false">"ã¢ãã¿ã¼ãã«ã¹"</string>`

As we can see charaters are unreadables.

All files are UTF-8 encoded.

If instead of putting the variable in the gradle.properties I put it directly on build.gradle `resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME_JAPANESE', "日本語"`, everything is working properly.

Could this be a bug in the gradle system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried changing the encoding but, still the same issue is happening.

Finally I decided to set the strings in base64 format and then decode the strings in the build.gradle like this

```
resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME_JA', new String(APP_NAME_JA.decodeBase64(), "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Java `properties` files by definition are **not** UTF-8 encoded, unless you explicitly parse them as UTF-8 files.

They are by default ISO-8859-1 encoded with unicode escapes for characters out of that range.

Fix your properties file and everything will work like a charm.

As you are using android I guess you are using Android Studio which is just a specialized IntelliJ IDEA. There you can change in the settings the encoding for properties files to ISO-8859-1 with transparent native-to-ascii escaping. This allows you to see the UTF-8 glyphs in the editor, but the file will be saved automatically with the unicode escapes as necessary. Alternatively you can use the `native2ascii` tool on the UTF-8 encoded properties file to do that transformation before you start your actual build. But I really recommend using the proper encoding that most tools that can deal with property files are expecting.